# How can I keep the bubble from a JRadioButton when adding an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jradiobutton

I am improving a rock, paper, scissors program I created using swing, and now I'm adding ImageIcons for each JRadioButton. I imported and added rock, but I cannot seem to find a way to keep the bubble

[image]

that is shown next to the text. When I add the icon, I get this.

[image]

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have enough reputation to do that @rocking

Comment: Yes I know thats why I helped you in editing

Comment: Combine a JRadioButton with a JLabel on one JPanel using a BorderLayout. Add the Icon to the JLabel, not the JRadioButton.

Comment: @ZeroConnor apparently _he_ didn't hehe. deleted his comment after realization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"How can I keep the bubble from a JRadioButton when adding an ImageIcon?"*

Maybe you group the icons and the RBs into separate panels

- Create a panel for each rock, paper, and scissors
- Add the radio button and the label of the image to the panel
- Add those panels to another panel to hold all three

Something like this

```
JRadioButton rock = new JRadioButton("Rock");
JRadioButton paper = new JRadioButton("Paper");
JRadioButton scissors = new JRadioButton("Scissors");

ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(rock);
bg.add(paper);
bg.add(scissors);

JPanel rockPanel = new JPanel();                         <-- Rock panel
rockPanel.add(rock);                                     <-- Rock RB
rockPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("rock.png"));     <-- Rock Icon

JPanel paperPanel = new JPanel();                        <-- Paper Panel
rockPanel.add(paper);                                    <-- Paper RB
rockPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("paper.png"));    <-- Paper Icon

JPanel scissorsPanel = new JPanel();                     <-- Scissors Panel
rockPanel.add(scissors);                                 <-- Scissors RB
rockPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("scissors.png")); <-- Scissors Icon

JPanel holdThreePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
holdThreePanel.add(rockPanel);                           <-- Rock Panel
holdThreePanel.add(paperPanel);                          <-- Paper Panel
holdThreePanel.add(scissorsPanel);                       <-- Scissors Panel
```

Then you'll have something like this

```
        holdThreePanel
--------------------------------
|  O  Rock     [rock icon]     |
|  O  Paper    [paper icon]    |
|  O  Scissors [scissors icon] |
+------------------------------+
```

If you don't want the text, don't set any text to the RadioButton. `JRadioButton rock = new RadioButton();`

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom icon for selection (May be add a border to the current icon). Then you can set the selection icon as below.

```
JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton(new ImageIcon("Resources/nonSelect.png"));
radio.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("Resources/selected.png"));
```

Additionally you can set a rollover icon as well.

```
radio.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon("Resources/rollover.png"));
```